# validate loaded weight empty weight form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weight data form and i want to make a validation on it where net weight = loaded weight - empty weight, if not the form not submit

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <legend class="h5 text-center text-danger">empty weight</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">empty weight</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="empty_weight"
         name="empty_weight" min="15000" max="35000" step="20" oncopy="return false"
         onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend class="h5 text-center text-danger">loaded weight</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">loaded weight</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="loaded_weight"
         name="loaded_weight" min="35000" max="120000" maxlength="6" step="20"
         oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend class="h5 text-center text-danger">net weight</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">net weight</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg font-weight-bolder" id="net_weight"
         name="net_weight" maxlength="5" step="20" oncopy="return false"
         onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ui-button">تاكيد</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">اغلاق</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the failure condition?

Comment: if net weight != loaded weight - empty weight form will not submit

Comment: you can use form's [onsubmit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) for that